Element type is invalid: expected a string - but the import implementation seems correct
frontend\src\components\CronJobTable.js:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Table, Button, Form, InputGroup, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

function CronJobTable() {
  const [cronJobs, setCronJobs] = useState([]);
  const [newCronJob, setNewCronJob] = useState({
    minute: '',
    hour: '',
    day: '',
    month: '',
    weekday: '',
    command: '',
  });

  const [validationErrors, setValidationErrors] = useState({});

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setNewCronJob({ ...newCronJob, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    setValidationErrors({ ...validationErrors, [e.target.name]: '' }); // Clear error on change
  };

  const validateCronExpression = (expression, fieldName) => {
    // You can implement a more robust validation using a cron parsing library here
    // For now, let's do a basic check for allowed characters and ranges
    const allowedChars = /[\*,\/\-0-9]/;
    if (!allowedChars.test(expression)) {
      setValidationErrors({ ...validationErrors, [fieldName]: 'Invalid characters' });
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };

  const addCronJob = () => {
    const isValidMinute = validateCronExpression(newCronJob.minute, 'minute');
    const isValidHour = validateCronExpression(newCronJob.hour, 'hour');
    const isValidDay = validateCronExpression(newCronJob.day, 'day');
    const isValidMonth = validateCronExpression(newCronJob.month, 'month');
    const isValidWeekday = validateCronExpression(newCronJob.weekday, 'weekday');

    if (isValidMinute && isValidHour && isValidDay && isValidMonth && isValidWeekday) {
      setCronJobs([...cronJobs, newCronJob]);
      setNewCronJob({
        minute: '',
        hour: '',
        day: '',
        month: '',
        weekday: '',
        command: '',
      });
      setValidationErrors({}); // Clear all errors
    }
  };

  const deleteCronJob = (index) => {
    setCronJobs(cronJobs.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Add New Cron Job</h2>
      <Form>
        <Form.Row>
          <Form.Group as={Col}>
            <Form.Label>Minute:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              name="minute"
              value={newCronJob.minute}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              isInvalid={!!validationErrors.minute}
            />
            <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
              {validationErrors.minute}
            </Form.Control.Feedback>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group as={Col}>
            <Form.Label>Hour:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              name="hour"
              value={newCronJob.hour}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              isInvalid={!!validationErrors.hour}
            />
            <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
              {validationErrors.hour}
            </Form.Control.Feedback>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>
        <Form.Row>
          <Form.Group as={Col}>
            <Form.Label>Day:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              name="day"
              value={newCronJob.day}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              isInvalid={!!validationErrors.day}
            />
            <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
              {validationErrors.day}
            </Form.Control.Feedback>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group as={Col}>
            <Form.Label>Month:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              name="month"
              value={newCronJob.month}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              isInvalid={!!validationErrors.month}
            />
            <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
              {validationErrors.month}
            </Form.Control.Feedback>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group as={Col}>
            <Form.Label>Weekday:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              name="weekday"
              value={newCronJob.weekday}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              isInvalid={!!validationErrors.weekday}
            />
            <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
              {validationErrors.weekday}
            </Form.Control.Feedback>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>Command:</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control 
            type="text" 
            name="command" 
            value={newCronJob.command} 
            onChange={handleInputChange} 
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={addCronJob}>
          Add New Cron Job
        </Button>
      </Form>

      <br />

      <h2>Current Cron Jobs</h2>
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Minute</th>
            <th>Hour</th>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Weekday</th>
            <th>Command</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {cronJobs.map((cronJob, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{cronJob.minute}</td>
              <td>{cronJob.hour}</td>
              <td>{cronJob.day}</td>
              <td>{cronJob.month}</td>
              <td>{cronJob.weekday}</td>
              <td>{cronJob.command}</td>
              <td>
                <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => deleteCronJob(index)}>
                  Delete
                </Button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CronJobTable;

Then in the calling file frontend\src\pages\mainApp.js I do:
import CronJobTable from "../components/CronJobTable";

And I get the error on the React frontend:

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `CronJobTable`.
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `CronJobTable`.
    at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (http://192.168.1.34:3000/static/js/bundle.js:76423:21)
    at createFiberFromElement (http://192.168.1.34:3000/static/js/bundle.js:76444:19)
    at createChild (http://192.168.1.34:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65013:32)
    at reconcileChildrenArray (http://192.168.1.34:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65253:29)
    at reconcileChildFibers (http://192.168.1.34:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65595:20)
    at reconcileChildren (http://192.168.1.34:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68527:32)
    at updateHostComponent (http://192.168.1.34:3000/static/js/bundle.js:69171:7)
    at beginWork (http://192.168.1.34:3000/static/js/bundle.js:70616:18)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://192.168.1.34:3000/static/js/bundle.js:55602:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://192.168.1.34:3000/static/js/bundle.js:55646:20)


